# Как вывести имя экземпляра класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу чтобы в методе `__str__()` выводилось имя экземпляра класса, не знаю как это сделать.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'name : {self.__name__()} .Size : [{self.n};{self.m}]. Matrix : {self.matrix}'
```

Comment: Имя экземпляра т.е. имя переменной, которая содержит ссылку на текущий объект? Или имя класса текущего объекта? Если название класса, то: `self.__class__.__name__`

Comment: @джилдевятьред я думаю глупо запрашивать имя класса, где происходит действо, так что скорее всего переменная)

Comment: @gil9red переменной

Comment: А что вам мешает взять это имя просто в кавычки, ничего не вызывая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы вернуть имя переменной, можно поискать наш объект в [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

Пример:

```
class Foo:
    def get_var_name(self):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if v is self:
                return k

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Foo var={self.get_var_name()}>'

foo = Foo()
print(foo)
# <Foo var=foo>
```

Ссылку на один объект можно хранить в нескольких переменных, поэтому можно искать все совпадения:

```
class Foo:
    def get_var_names(self):
        return [k for k, v in globals().items() if v is self]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Foo var={self.get_var_names()}>'

foo = Foo()
bar = foo
abc = bar
print(foo)
# <Foo var=['foo', 'bar', 'abc']>
```

**Минус алгоритма** -- он работает только с глобальными переменными, поэтому локальные переменные не будут видны:

```
def go():
    foo = Foo()
    bar = foo
    abc = bar
    print(foo)

go()
# <Foo var=[]>
```