# Как избавиться от рекурсии в магическом методе абстрактного класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

На сколько я понимаю в абстрактном классе можно хранить какое-то общее поведение для дочерних классов.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить магический метод `__str__` в абстрактном классе, чтобы при печати экземпляров дочерних классов выводилась строчка: `данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре (имя экземпляра)` У меня сейчас получается ошибка рекурсии, на сколько я понимаю, из-за того, что при печати `{self}` он как раз не находя метода ищет его Base, находит и так далее...,

```
from abc import ABC


class Base(ABC):
    def __str__(self):
        return f' Данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре {self}'


class A(Base):
    pass


class B(Base):
    pass


a, b = A(), B()
print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка рекурсии у вас выходит потому, что в этом фрагменте кода:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f' Данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре {self}'
                                                          ^^^^^^
```

для печати `{self}` питон получает строковое представление объекта `self`, для чего он опять вызывает `__str__(self)` и так по кругу.

Кроме того, экземпляры объектов в `Python` не имеют имён, хотя вы можете сами задать объекту имя при создании, запомнить его в `__init__` и потом печатать его.

Пример кода, который работает без ошибки и выводит `id` объекта:

```
class Base(ABC):
    def __str__(self):
        return f' Данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре {id(self)}'
```

Вывод (у вас будут другие цифры, конечно):

```
Данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре 140550787401712  Данный метод сейчас вызывается в экземпляре 140550787401656
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к вышеизложенному. Нашёл как можно вывести имя экземпляра класса, используя `globals()`
см. [Как вывести имя экземпляра класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072857/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: Да, это в общем логичный вариант, я про него думал, но забыл написать )